# PHP - odd one out

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a "find the odd word" application (given a list of words like cat, dog, bird and car, the latter is the odd one because it's not an animal).

Firstly, I retrieve and shuffle randomly five words from the DB. They are called: odd (which is the odd one), one, two, three, four (which are the other four).

Then, I produce a form (radio button) with the five words, so that users can select one of their choice:

```
$words = array
(
    $odd,
    $one,
    $two,
    $three,
    $four,
);
shuffle($words);

foreach ($words as $word)
   {
     $string = $word;
     echo '<html><input type="radio" name="odd" value="'.$string.'">'.$string.'<br><br></html>';
   }
```

In the next PHP page, I want to check if the selected word is the odd one. I can't figure out how to do it.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: cat dog bird car, the odd word for me is bird, four letters...!

Comment: You should remove those html tags from your loop. You don't want to create a new html document with each loop. You should only be printing the input tags.

Comment: in your form request, you also need to pass back a variable to identify the question (like question_id), then check against your db to see if the answer is correct

Comment: how do you select which one is the odd word in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the $_SESSION variable to handle this to find out if the odd was selected or not

Say the following code is from your Odd.php that displays the radio buttons (assuming you would handle the form element and submit button)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['odd'] = $odd;

    $words = array
    (
        $odd,
        $one,
        $two,
        $three,
        $four,
    );

    shuffle($words);
    echo '<form method="POST" action="Next.php">';
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        $string = $word;
        echo '<input type="radio" name="odd" value="'.$string.'">'.$string.'<br><br>';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" /></form>';
?>
```

On your Next.php file use the code below to validate if the odd was selected or not

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $odd = $_SESSION['odd'];
    if ($_REQUEST['odd'] == $odd) { // $_REQUEST handles both $_POST and $_GET
        echo "Odd was selected";
    } else {
        echo "Odd was not selected";
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to carry the odd word to the next page somehow. There are many different ways of doing this, arguably the easiest one is by saving the odd word in a variable in your form

```html
<input type="hidden" name="realodd" value="<?php print $odd; ?>" />
```

On the next page, you can then check whether the chosen word is right by comparing it to the hidden word.

```
if ($_POST['realodd'] == $_POST['odd']) {
  print "You found the odd word.";
}
```

This could easily be broken by just looking at the source code. A better solution could be saving the odd word in a session cookie:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['realodd'] = $odd;
```

And then verify on the next page almost like before

```
if ($_SESSION['realodd'] == $_POST['odd']) {
  print "You found the odd word.";
}
```

Comment: that's what I was wondering about, but realised I should post this comment on the question^^.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['odd'])&& isset($_SESSION['odd'])&& $_POST['odd']==$_SESSION['odd']){
  exit ("You're a genius, you got the right word");
}else{
  if (isset($_POST['odd'])){ echo "Sorry, try again";}
}

   //sql query goes here

$words = array
(
    $odd,
    $one,
    $two,
    $three,
    $four,
);
$_SESSION['odd'] = $odd;
shuffle($words);
    echo '<form method="POST">';
foreach ($words as $word)
   {
     echo '<input type="radio" name="odd" value="$word"/>$word<br><br>';
   }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>';
    echo '</form>';
```